# escape a sql query error message using Perl

Tags: mysql, perl, csv

J have my inventory data inside a csv file.
I get an error message because I have a special character on my insert values, I don't want to deal with those values because they were tagged with special characters $" to not use them anymore for insert. I use the code bellow:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# PERL MODULES WE WILL BE USING
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;

# HTTP HEADER
print "Content-type: text/html \n\n";

# CONFIG VARIABLES
$platform = "mysql";
$database = "store";
$host = "localhost";
$port = "3306";
$tablename = "inventory";
$user = "username";
$pw = "password";

# DATA SOURCE NAME
$dsn = "dbi:$platform:$database:$host:$port";

# PERL DBI CONNECT
$connect = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw);

# PREPARE THE QUERY
$query = "INSERT INTO inventory (id, product, quantity) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'tomatoes$"', '4')";
$query_handle = $connect->prepare($query);

# EXECUTE THE QUERY
$query_handle->execute();
```

How can I skipe the error message and move to the next insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to escape the $ in your query, because right now it's a perl syntax error:

```
$sql = "INSERT .... 'tomatoes$"', '4')";
                              ^----
```

that quote TERMINATES the sql string, as it's not a valid variable. Try

```
$sql = "INSERT .... 'tomatoes\$"', '4')";
                             ^--
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you very much Marc for your response, I would like to know how can I escape the sql error. because the insert that generate errors I would like to throw that data away and not insert them into the table.

Comment: look for `$"` in your data before you go anywhere near the database stuff. if it's present in the data, then simply skip the entire database operation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!!!!! that is exactly what I was looking for! please update you answer because I would love to mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 1):

Handle your insert sentence avoiding sql-injection:

```
my $query = qq!INSERT INTO inventory (id, product, quantity) VALUES (?,?,?)!;
my $query_handle = $connect->prepare($query);

$query_handle->execute('DEFAULT', 'tomatoes$', '4');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the tipe!!! I would like to know how can escape an error generated by SQL query. mean that if the query has an error, don't do any insert and don't display any error. Thanks a lot again Miguel!!!

Comment: The OP doesn't indent to inject (improperly or otherwise)